# Reason for file lock while bulkcopy its data to table

Tags: c#

I'm browsing a `.MDF` file and uploading its data to a SQL Server database table.

My app has a browse button to select the file and then upload button to perform the bulkcopy operation.

But in second attempt when I choose the `.mdf` file using `OpenFileDialog`, it throws an error saying the file is already being used.

```
private void labelBrowse_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog.Title = "Select the MDF file to upload";
        openFileDialog.Filter = "Data|*.mdf";
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            textBoxMdfFilePath.Text = openFileDialog.FileName.ToString();
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}

private void labelUpload_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxMdfFilePath.Text.Trim()))
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Please select a MDF file to upload");
        textBoxMdfFilePath.Text = "";
        return;
    }
    else if (!(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(textBoxMdfFilePath.Text).Equals("Audit.mdf", System.StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) && !(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(textBoxMdfFilePath.Text).Equals("IPAUDIT.mdf", System.StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Please select the correct MDF file to upload");
        textBoxMdfFilePath.Text = "";
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        uploadToServer(textBoxMdfFilePath.Text);
    }
}

void uploadToServer(string path)
{
    try
    {
        string mdfConnectionString = @"data source=172.16.2.136;attachdbfilename=" + path + ";" + "integrated security=true;" + "connect timeout=30;" + "user instance=true";
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlconnection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(mdfConnectionString);

        if (System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path).Equals("Audit.mdf", System.StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand sqlcommand = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("select * from [D-Audit]", sqlconnection);

            sqlconnection.Open();
            System.Data.DataTable dataTable = new System.Data.DataTable();
            dataTable.Load(sqlcommand.ExecuteReader());
            sqlconnection.Close();

            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy sqlbulkcopy = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myServerAudit"].ConnectionString);
            sqlbulkcopy.DestinationTableName = "[dbo].[D-Audit]";
            sqlbulkcopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 1800;
            sqlbulkcopy.WriteToServer(dataTable);
            sqlbulkcopy.Close();

            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Data Uploaded Successfully");
            textBoxMdfFilePath.Text = "";
        }
        else if (System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path).Equals("IPAudit.mdf", System.StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand sqlcommand = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("select * from IpTransaction", sqlconnection);

            sqlconnection.Open();
            System.Data.DataTable dataTable = new System.Data.DataTable();
            dataTable.Load(sqlcommand.ExecuteReader());
            sqlconnection.Close();

            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy sqlbulkcopy = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myServerIPAudit"].ConnectionString);
            sqlbulkcopy.DestinationTableName = "IpTransaction";
            sqlbulkcopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 1800;
            sqlbulkcopy.WriteToServer(dataTable);
            sqlbulkcopy.Close();

            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Data Uploaded Successfully");
            textBoxMdfFilePath.Text = "";
        }

        sqlconnection.Close();

    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: did you got error first time ?

Comment: No, 1st time the file is selectable, but 2nd time it will throw error that "the file is being used"

Comment: Which line of code locks down the file and how to release it

Comment: `.mdf` files are **SQL Server** database files - and those are typically attached to a SQL Server instance, and if so, that SQL Server process will **lock those files** and you cannot just browse to it and grab it. And that's a *good thing*, too ! Leave the `.mdf` files to SQL Server - don't fiddle around with them - just let them be

Comment: No, the mdf file which I'm using are not attached to SQL server, they have been brought from other systems and are being used in my application in a different system.

Comment: Sqlbulkcopy is of IDisposable type....Wrap it in Using block, no need to call close and try again

Comment: Used the "using", still issue not resolved

Comment: Yes, you have to do one more thing.....SQLBulkCopy is creating its own instance of SQLConnction with pooling enabled.....Updated your connection string with Pooling=false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set Pooling=False in your connection string

Whats happening here is SQLBulkcopy is creating its own SQLConnection object with connection string you provided. By default, the Connection Pool is true...so when sqlconnection object is created by SQLBulkCopy, it is added in connection pool and connection persists even after application is closed.This mechanism is to optimize performance but in your case that's what is causing issue...so adding Pooling=false in your connection should solve your problem

```
ConnectionString  = "Data Source=MYSQL;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=true;Pooling=false"
```

**Additinal Info**

It is good practice to wrap your SQLBulkCopy with Using block as it is of type IDisposable so you need not call close explicitly.

Comment: Thanks buddy, It worked after setting pooling=false in the connection string

Answer (score 0):

When you say on "second attempt", I'm assuming it works on first click but not on subsequent clicks. If that's the case, then the connection is probably not being released and still holding on to the DB. You may try disposing all IDisposables in your code before leaving the event handler.

Comment: That's what I'm confused about, I want to know why the connection is not being released though I have already closed it. If any other thing is there which locks the file ?

Comment: Try passing an explicit Connection object (which you have opened) to the SqlBulkCopy constructor. And then call Close on that connection after SqlBulkCopy.Close(). Currently you're passing a connection string and letting SqlBulkCopy manage the lifetime of the connection.